# Windows Phone WrapPanel behaving differntly with design data and at runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro

I'm using a WrapPanel as a part of an ItemsControl in a WP8 application. everything works fine including it's designtime data view, and I'm using the same ViewModel with a WinRT application which uses a WrapGrid (which works both designtime and runtime)

While all the other elements of the View show up on runtime perfectly, the Itemscontrol does not populate, is there any known issue with the WrapPanel, how do I show a gridlike view of my items then? the code I've used is below

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="times" Background="{x:Null}" Height="120" ItemsSource="{Binding CheckinTimes}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource BoxStyle}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,10" Width="70" >
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" Margin="0" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="13.333" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Margin="0" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="13.333" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
</ItemsControl>
```

under resources

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="BoxStyle">
        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hiding the control before populating it, but the visibility was wrongly bound. I corrected that and it fixed this issue, I'm not sure how it's related but it worked. I would say for any similar errors, watch the bindings around control visibility.